# 2 Line Button Value

Tags: html, css, button

I want to make a button like this.

[image: button example]

As you can see, there is 2 lines and lines' font size is different . Is this possible with using CSS + HTML (and maybe JS) ? I don't want to use image for button.

(Font face doens't matter)

Thank you ;)

Comment: You can style a div with anchors. Using CSS and playing with margins/background/corners it could be done. (though your font would need to be on the visitor's machine).

Comment: Font doesn't matter. I want to make a button which it's value has 2 lines.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<button>
<span style="font-size:16px;">1st Line</span><br />
<span style="font-size:12px;">2nd Line</span>
</button>
```

Should work

Comment: William, can you help me ? Is there default margins for `<button>` ? http://www.girmiyor.com/ this page, as you can see, button is upper than text-box.

Comment: There probably is, so try setting margin to 0 in CSS.

Comment: Sorry, I am on my phone at the moment, so I can't check the source code. But I would check for anything such as a margin, padding, top, left, right, bottom, etc. in CSS that might cause the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Somethink like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/36fcw/2/

Answer (score 3):

Put `&#10;` where you want to break the line

Answer (score 0):

form elements are always a pain to design out... best walk through is to put form elements in table.. hope this helps you. [Your form within table and some css..](http://jsfiddle.net/naveedahmedji/gv33v/30/)