# "\n" does not work inside an ASP:Button for Internet Explorer 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, internet-explorer-10

I have some text on a button that I want to put on a new line inside the button I did this:

```
btn.Text = "Find\n Transactions";
```

This works fine on Internet Explorer 9, but not on Internet Explorer 10.

I have also tried environment.newline variation, but this didn't work.

Comment: possible duplicate of [2 Line Button Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5053707/2-line-button-value)

Comment: @walther I'm sorry did I not specifically state ASP:BUTTON?

Comment: Another way, you can try using `asp.net` `LinkButton` which is rendered as `<a />` and you can add some html inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use this:

```
Environment.NewLine();
```

Like this:

```
btn.text = "some" + Environment.NewLine() + "text";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try vbCrLf, and of course if you are in a web applciation, try `<br />`

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<asp:Button Text="Hello&#010;World" runat="server" ID="cmdHello" />
```